# execute a command in $PATH matching a wildcard

Tags: shell, wildcards, path, portability

I'd like to find and execute a command in the current `$PATH` matching this wildcard `libreoffice?.?` (eg. `libreoffice4.0`, `libreoffice4.3`, etc.)

EDIT: if multiple matches are found, you can pick one randomly.

I prefer a POSIX compliant solution.

Answer (score 4):

Set `IFS` to `:` to split the value of `PATH` on colons. If your `find` has the `-quit` action and the `-maxdepth` primary (e.g. FreeBSD, OSX, GNU), you know the command will exist and you don't care about the command's return code, you can use this one-liner:

```
pattern='libreoffice?.?'
IFS=:; find $PATH -maxdepth 1 -type f -name "$pattern" -exec {} \; -quit; unset IFS
```

This doesn't provide an easy way to report whether the command was found. Furthermore, to be more robust, turn off globbing in case the value of `PATH` contains wildcards. Also, it's possible to have an empty component in `PATH` to mean the current directory (but my advice is to use `.` instead). The code below takes care of all these complications.

```
pattern='libreoffice?.?'
case $PATH in
  :*) directories=.$PATH;;
  *::*) directories=${PATH%%::*}:.:${PATH#*::};;
  *:) directories=$PATH.;;
  *) directories=$PATH;;
esac
set -f; IFS=:
cmd=
for d in $directories; do
  set +f
  for x in "$d"/$pattern; do
    if [ -x "$x" ] && ! [ -d "$x" ]; then
      cmd=$x
      break
    fi
  done
  if [ -n "$cmd" ]; then break; fi
done
set +f; unset IFS
if [ -z "$cmd" ]; then
  echo 1>&2 "$pattern: not found in PATH"
  exit 127
else
  exec "$cmd"
fi
```

If you happen to be using zsh (as opposed to plain sh, bash, ksh, …), it's a lot simpler to make a robust solution.

```
pattern='libreoffice?.?'
matches=($^path/$~pattern(N.*[1]))
if ((!#matches)); then
  $matches[1]
else
  echo 1>&2 "$pattern: not found in PATH"
  exit 127
fi
```

Comment: Strictly speaking, `::` could occur more than once in `$PATH`. You may want to consider the case where `$PATH` is set but empty as well (replace with `.`).

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas - per our previous conversation `::` assuming `.` for `::` is only legacy conformant anyway - and newer applications should make such an assumption.

Comment: I prefer the oneliner solution, but with posix-compatible switches: `find $PATH -type f -perm /u=x,g=x,o=x -prune -name "$@" | head -n1`

Comment: @eadmaster You're recursing into subdirectories into directories in `$PATH` (and yes, that does happen).

Comment: `"$@"` is the pattern , because i've wrapped everything in a script...

Comment: @eadmaster Make that `"$1"`, since there can only be one pattern here.

Answer (score 2):

POSIXly, when searching for a `$PATH`'d executable *command*, you should use [`command`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/command.html):

- `command -v`

  - Write a string to standard output that indicates the pathname or command that will be used by the shell, in the current shell execution environment *(see [Shell Execution Environment](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_12)*, to invoke *command_name*, but do not invoke *command_name*.
  - ... Otherwise, no output shall be written and the exit status shall reflect that the name was not found.

If called eithout a switch, `command` *will* invoke *command_name*, but you do still need a fully resolved path to fully resolve a [shell glob](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_13).

So, to do that, you should check the glob against each `:` colon-separated element in `$PATH` in order, as [spec'd](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009696899/basedefs/xbd_chap08.html):

- `PATH`

  - This variable shall represent the sequence of path prefixes that certain functions and utilities apply in searching for an executable file known only by a *filename*. The prefixes shall be separated by a colon `:`. When a non-zero-length prefix is applied to this filename, a slash shall be inserted between the prefix and the filename. A zero-length prefix is a *legacy feature* that indicates the current working directory. It appears as two adjacent colons `::` , as an initial colon preceding the rest of the list, or as a trailing colon following the rest of the list. **A strictly conforming application shall use an actual pathname *(such as `.`)* to represent the current working directory in `PATH`**. The list shall be searched from beginning to end, applying the *filename* to each prefix, until an executable file with the specified name and appropriate execution permissions is found. If the *pathname* being sought contains a slash, the search through the path prefixes shall not be performed. If the *pathname* begins with a slash, the specified path is resolved *(see [Pathname Resolution](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009696899/basedefs/xbd_chap04.html#tag_04_11))*. **If `PATH` is unset or is set to null, the path search is implementation-defined**.

You can split out `$PATH` into a [*field*](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_05) per `$PATH` component on [`$IFS`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_05_02), but you can only do this safely if you also [`set -f`ilename expansion](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_06) as disabled while you do, in case a component in `$PATH` contains any of `[?*` characters, because filename generation *(read: globbing)* occurs *after* field-splitting in the shell's expansion order.

In that way, in general, the only really robust way to do this POSIXly is to first expand the field list on `$IFS` while filename generation is disabled and to somehow save that array result, then to once again enable filename generation *and* disable field-splitting *(so that you might store and expand your glob pattern [unquoted](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_02) in a variable w/out any danger of it being affected by `$IFS` first)*, and operate on the results each in turn.

Fortunately, this is not so difficult:

```
g='libreoffice?.?'
(   IFS=:; set -f             #split on :; disable filename gen
    set +f -- $PATH          #store split array, enable filename gen after
    IFS=                     #disable field splitting
    for p do for x in ${p:+"$p/"$g}
          do command -v "$x"
    done;done
)                            #done in subshell to avoid affecting current shell
```

The last bits there are not commented because they're better explained here.

- `for p do` - The first `for` loop iteratively assigns `$p` the value of each positional parameter in the [shell's `"$@"` array](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_05_02), which are [`set`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#set) to the the field-split expansion of `$PATH` as divided by `:` colons.
- `for x in ${p:+"$p/"$g}` - The inner `for` loop iteratively sets `$x` to each *(if any)* of the expansions of [`${p:+"$p/"$g}`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_02) - which is to say, it iterates over nothing at all unless `$p` is both set and not-null. This is important because `::` or a leading `:` would split out to null fields, and, in this way, the two loops *strictly conform* to the `$PATH` spec *(as quoted above)* by not acknowledging *zero-length* fields.
- Importantly, because of the way `$PATH` is split while filename generation is disabled and `"$p/"$g` is resolved while it is enabled but field-splitting has been disabled, none of the elements in `$PATH` can expand to anything but their fields as split on `:` *(regardless of whatever other characters they may contain)* and neither can any value for `"$p/"$g` expand to anything but itself or whatever filenames it might match *(regardless of any characters in `$p` or other than pattern-matching characters `$g` might contain)*.
- `command` - and last `command` only prints to standard-out those values for `$x` which are executable commands.

Here's the whole thing wrapped in a shell function, with the additional capability of handling multiple `$g` arguments:

```
glob_path()( 
    for g do IFS=:; set -f
          set +f -- ${PATH:-.}; IFS=
          for p do for x in ${p:+"$p/"$g}
                do command -v "$x"
    done; done; done
)
```

That should get you a list of executables matching each argument you hand it printed one per line ordered first by argument order, then by `$PATH` priority, and last by your locale's sort order. It should not fail on newlines or special characters in the pathnames or the glob patterns you hand it. It might be altered *(see the edit history here)* to faithfully populate the shell `"$@"` array at one executable per positional parameter.

You could also alter it to execute the first successful glob match and quit searching for that particular glob argument and to move onto the next if the command exits successfully like...

```
glob_path()( 
    for g do IFS=:; set -f
          set +f -- ${PATH:-.}; IFS=
          for p do for x in ${p+:"$p/"$g}
                do command -v "$x" &&
                   command "$x"    &&
                   break 2
    done; done; done
)
```

This is a POSIX portable means of finding your glob match, but some shells don't even need the the second `for g...` loop. In `bash`, for example, this will also work like...

```
glob_path()( 
    for g do IFS=:; set -f
          set +f -- ${PATH:-.}; IFS=
          for p do command -v ${p:+"$p/"$g}
    done; done
)
```

...which still lists every executable glob match for all arguments and for each element in `$PATH` regardless of whether any of those elements or glob patterns contain newlines, or special characters, etc.

You can use it like:

```
glob_path '?sh' '??sh'       #I'd rather not install libreoffice
```

...which for me prints...

```
/usr/bin/ksh
/usr/bin/rsh
/usr/bin/ssh
/usr/bin/zsh
/usr/local/bin/dash
/usr/local/bin/yash
/usr/bin/bash
/usr/bin/bssh
/usr/bin/chsh
/usr/bin/dash
/usr/bin/mksh
/usr/bin/posh
/usr/bin/slsh
/usr/bin/yash
```

As already discussed, the `glob_path` function interprets the `$PATH` environment variable as the spec states a *strictly conforming* application should by ignoring leading, trailing or consecutive `:` occurrences in `$PATH`'s value, but it does interpret an empty or unset `$PATH` to mean `.`.

If you did want that legacy feature though, the function could be written:

```
glob_path()(
    for g do IFS=:; set -f
          set +f -- ${0+$PATH:}; IFS=
          for p do for x in "${p:-.}/"$g
                do command -v "$x"
    done; done; done
)
```

...which would interpret all occurrences of leading, trailing, or two consecutive `:` colons to mean `.` *(and so search `.` as many times as a zero-length `$PATH` component appears in `$PATH`'s value)*, but that's not strictly conformant.

Comment: i prefer dgsleeps' answer because looks simpler...

Comment: Fails if `$PATH` contains empty components. Also, note that IFS considers : as a delimiter, not separator as you'd need to process $PATH (values of `$PATH` like `/bin:/usr/bin:` are not unusual)

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas - Good point - I had that in the older one. What does the *Also...* mean? Are you saying it is possible for a `$PATH` component to contain `:`? Anyway; I fixed the `::` thing.

Comment: `IFS=:; $PATH` splits `/bin:/usr/bin:` into `(/bin /usr/bin)` in POSIX shells, not `(/bin /usr/bin '')` (exception with `zsh` in sh emulation, yash, pdksh and older versions of mksh)

Comment: An empty $PATH means search in the current directory, `/bin:` means search in /bin and current directory. For an _unset_ $PATH, that depends on the shell, check my answer on the _why not use which question_. See @Gilles' for a more correct method.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas - meh, I added a version that will do the zero-length thing *(and, if you assume that behavior is correct, then more correct than Gilles does it)*, but I still don't recommend it.

Comment: _application_ in the posix spec is on the user side. It just says one shouldn't use values of PATH like `:/bin:/usr/bin` (that one is the default for execp on GNU/Linux) _implementations_ are still required to treat that empty component as the current directory.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas - That doesn't make sense. Any *application* shall treat an actual pathname to represent the current working directory in PATH - which means that any actual application reading PATH shall not treat :: in PATH to represent `.` because only an *actual pathname* should. This is the only information on the subject I've found - where do you get the information on which you base that?

Comment: Again, _application_ means the _user_ of that API that POSIX specifies. A POSIX _script_ should not use an empty component, a POSIX _implementation_ (of the API, as in `sh`), must consider an empty component as meaning the same as `.` (as specified in the description of `$PATH` [there](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html#tag_08))

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas - That's the same description of `$PATH` I've posted in the answer here...? And I just don't understand why you interpret it that way. `PATH` is *applied* by the implementation and *set* by the user - logically, to me, this seems to directly contradict your interpretation.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas - The `sh` spec does add this, though: *If the variables ... are present in the environment during the execution of an application or utility, they shall be given the meaning described below. Some are placed into the environment by the implementation ...; all can be added or changed by the user... The implementation adds or changes environment variables named in POSIX.1-2008 only as specified in POSIX.1-2008. If they are defined ... they have the specified meaning. Conforming applications shall not set these environment variables to have meanings other than as described.*

Answer (score 2):

Here's a simpler alternative:

```
$(compgen -c libreoffice)
```

It assumes bash, and assumes there's only one `libreoffice*` installed.

It emulates what bash tab completion would do if you typed `libreoffice`<kbd>Tab</kbd>.

If you were deliberately trying to exclude `libreoffice` without a version number, and want to handle the existence of multiple versions, try:

```
run_libreoffice() {
    compgen -c libreoffice |
        while read -r exe; do
            case "$exe" in libreoffice?.?)
                "$exe" "$@"
                return
                ;;
            esac
        done
}
run_libreoffice "$@"
```

The `case` statement makes it match only `libreoffice?.?`, and we loop over the results, only running the first one.

Comment: It assumes more than `bash` - it assumes one full result per line, and no `$IFS` or glob characters in results.

Comment: that's an interesting option, but it is limited to wildcards starting with a fixed string...

Comment: The second form isn't limited to fixed strings, but having to specify the substring to `compgen` then the pattern to `case` isn't ideal.

Answer (score 2):

With `zsh`:

```
$commands[(i)libreoffice?.?]
```

In `zsh`, `$commands` is a special associative array whose keys are command names and value their path.

`i` above is an *array subscript flag* that tells `zsh` to match the pattern against the array keys and return the first matching key.

The elements of the associative array are not in any particular order though, so the *first* matching key will not necessarily be the first that occurs in `$PATH`. If you want the `libreoffice` with the greatest version number, you could do:

```
${${(nO)${commands[(I)libreoffice?.?]}}[1]}
```

The `I` subscript flag expands to *all* the matching keys. We use the `n` (numerical sort), and `O` (reverse order) *parameter expansion flags* to sort that list from greatest to smallest version number, and then `[1]` to select the first one.

See also:

```
whence -m 'libreoffice?.?'
```

to find the paths of the corresponding commands.

Comment: @mikeserv, it reports the key, so the command name, the normal $PATH lookup will invoke the first in $PATH for the greatest version of libreoffice (and `$commands[cmd]` is the first `cmd` in `$PATH`, it's just that if you have `/bin/libreoffice4.2` and `/usr/bin/libreoffice4.1`, the first solution may very well return `libreoffice4.1` even if `/bin` is before `/usr/bin` in `$PATH`). In `zsh`, the `$path` array is _tied_ to the `$PATH` scalar (a feature borrowed from csh)

Comment: But I thought `$path` can be altered without altering `$PATH`? Anyway, I know very little about that - only that they were separate things. Nope - tested it - changing `$path` also changed `$PATH`.

Comment: @mikerserv, no, `$path` and `$PATH` are tied. Any modification of one is reflected in the other. See the description of `typeset -T`.

Comment: Interesting... *The first two arguments are the name of a scalar and an array parameter (in that order) that will be tied together in the manner of `$PATH` and `$path`. The optional third argument is a single-character separator which will be used to join the elements of the array to form the scalar; if absent, a colon is used.* `zsh` sure does some neat stuff, it's just that it does *so much* of it that I often get lost. That's why, for the complicated stuff, I've learned to like `ksh93` much better - it's more straight-forward, as I think. But that's just preference.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the command "find" as follows

```
find ./ -name "libreoffice?.?"
```

Comment: does not work, note that i meant the system `$PATH`, not the `$PWD`

Comment: find $(echo $PATH|sed  's/:/ /g') -name "libreoffice?.?"

Comment: ok, it works! :)

Comment: In order to find into all $PATH directories we should do a search in all of it. This means something like this: 'find dir1 dir2 dir3 -name "libreoffice?.?"'. Therefore, what we just replace the semicolon for spaces with command  $(echo $PATH|sed 's/:/ /g')